# C++ get the user preferred encoding or locale encoding

Tags: python, c++, boost, encoding

I want to achieve the same result with the python codes in c++ :

```
import locale
encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding()
```

The`encoding` is 'cp936' on my PC(windows 10, Chinese Simplified)

I try the following C++ codes:

**test1.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <clocale>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    string lc_all = std::setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL);
    cout << lc_all << endl;  // prints Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
    return 0;
}
```

Hmm...I am still not satisfied, so I turn to `boost::locale`(boost_1_65_1), but there are some strange behaviours.

**test2.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <boost/locale.hpp>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    string encoding = std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(gen("")).encoding();
    cout << encoding << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem 1:** The codes will result in link errors, unless include another header: `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`, why? Is there any document to say to use `boost::locale` one also has to include `boost::filesystem`?

```
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(generator.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(date_time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(localization_backend.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(lcid.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(generator.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(date_time.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(localization_backend.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>libboost_locale-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib(lcid.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

**Problem 2:** By adding `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>`, the program runs, but `encoding` is "utf-8", why? I thought it to be 'cp936', consistent with the result of **test1.cpp**

**Question:** What's the best idea to get the locale encoding by c++(Achieve the same result with python's `locale.getpreferredencoding()`). Many thanks!

**Environment:** win10 64bit, vs2015, boost_1_65_1(windows pre-build, lib64-msvc-14.0)

Comment: Read the document first!

Comment: @Silencer How can you see I didn't read the doc? You could give a more useful comment, for example the right place of the so-called 'document'

Comment: It shows because http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/locale/doc/html/examples.html shows exactly what you need to do.

Comment: @UKMonkey thanks, but there's no solution for my problems. I've searched around for two days before raising the question.

Comment: I'm not really understand your question. I cann't guess whether you want to get or set encoding. I don't really want to ZheTeng on Win X. But the offical document or CSDN may help you for encoding "CP936". http://blog.csdn.net/aseity/article/details/48313099

Comment: @Silencer I think my purpose is very very clear by the leading two lines python codes(forgive me if you cannot understand it). But really thanks for the link, it solves my question. I don't want to ZheTeng Win x either! But the life f**ks me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

python `locale.getpreferredencoding()`'s equivalent:

```
std::string getpreferredencoding()
{
    std::string strCodePage = boost::locale::util::get_system_locale();
    std::locale loc = boost::locale::generator().generate(strCodePage);
    return std::use_facet<boost::locale::info>(loc).encoding();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Problem 1: The codes will result in link errors, unless include another header: #include , why? Is there any document to say to use boost::locale one also has to include boost::filesystem?

Auto-linking doesn't work as intended. This is a bug reportable to the boost library devs. In this particular case I'm going to ***guess***¹ Boost System should have been linked, and the Boost Locale/Boost System headers do not include the appropriate pragmas for that.

Including Boost Filesystem **happens** to solve the link error because it *does* have the library pragma

¹ because you fail to show the linker errors